# If math marks > 50 then this record prints otherwise give the message to try again

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arraylist

**students.forEach**

```
(

  student =>
{

**if(student.sub.math>50)**{

**result.push
({

name: student.name,

Subject: student.sub,

marks: Object.values(student.sub).reduce((a, b) => a + b),

Average: Object. values(student. sub).reduce((a, b) => a + b/300)**

 }
    
}
else
{
    console.log('Try again');
});
```

**console.log(result)**

Comment: add code snippets correctly to understand

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is currently unclear. Please read [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to write a good question.